# Problems for getting the values of two variables from the DragCanvas_ class inside another cs-file of the C# project.Is it the DragCanvas fault?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, move, drag

I have a WPF C# project with a DragCanvas_ class (see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas), so that I can move every Child-element, which I created in the MainWindow.xaml-file of the WPF-project between the Dragcanvas, i.e. between the `<jas:DragCanvas_ x:Name="dragCanvas_"` and                 `</jas:DragCanvas_>`in the xaml-code. The moving works by dragging the Child-elements by mouse (`OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)`).

Inside the DragCanvas_ public class I wrote the following code in order to get the coordinates of the Child-Elements from the DragCanvas as I move them around with the mouse. I can print them in the console at runtime with `Console.WriteLine();`inside the DragCanvas_ class, but I need the two coordinates inside the MainWindow.xaml.cs-file, i.e. inside the MainWindow.xaml.cs class. Inside the MainWindow.xaml.cs-file is a method, which has to take these two coordinates for repositioning the ROI_rectangles (the elements which are inside the DragCanvas_ for dragging).

Here is the code inside the DragCanvas_.cs-file (the DragCanvas_ class) for getting the two coordinates LeftMargin and TopMargin of the draggable elements inside the DragCanvas_:

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreviewMouseUp(e);

            var positionTransform = this.ElementBeingDragged.TransformToAncestor(this);
            var areaPosition = positionTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));


            // Reset the field whether the left or right mouse button was 
            // released, in case a context menu was opened on the drag element.
            this.ElementBeingDragged = null;
            if (this.ElementBeingDragged != null)
            {
                this.ElementBeingDragged = null;
            }
            LeftMargin = areaPosition.X;
            TopMargin = areaPosition.Y;
            //Console.WriteLine(LeftMargin);//these two work of course, but I need the two variables inside a method in another class of the C# project
            //Console.WriteLine(TopMargin);

        }
```

And the two variables LeftMargin and TopMargin are declared as public at the beginning of the DragCanvas_ class as follows:

```
public class DragCanvas_ : Canvas 
{

    public double LeftMargin { get; set; }
    public double TopMargin { get; set; }

 // the rest of the code...
}
```

For using the several values of the two Variables LeftMargin and TopMargin inside the MainWindow.xaml.cs-file I write inside the MainWindow.xaml.cs-file the following code:

```
namespace ABC
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
            
    
        DragCanvas_ myDragCanvasObject = new DragCanvas_(); // new instance of DragCanvas_ class
         if (myDragCanvasObject != null)
            {
                myDragCanvasObject = null;
            }

       Console.WriteLine(myDragCanvasObject.LeftMargin);
        Console.WriteLine(myDragCanvasObject.TopMargin); 

}
```

I also already added `public Window() : base() { }` between the `public partial class MainWindow : Window`
and the `static void Main(string[] args)`, but that did not help either.

I really don't know what to do and am desperate about this problem. I just can't figure out what the reason could be. Help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create a new instance of the `DragCanvas` in the code-behind. Instead you should access the properties of the one that you have already added in your XAML markup:

```
Console.WriteLine(dragCanvas_.LeftMargin);
Console.WriteLine(dragCanvas_.TopMargin);
```

"dragCanvas_" refers to the name of the element in the XAML markup:

```
<jas:DragCanvas_ x:Name="dragCanvas_" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried your suggestion, which makes sense, because the dragCanvas is already an objekt and refers to the name of the XAML markup. In the MainWindow.xaml.cs-file I wrote `public void WriteLeftMarginInConsole()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dragCanvas_.TopMargin);

        }` TopMargin at first as an example. But the console does not show the pixels in the console. If I write `Console.WriteLine(TopMargin);` inside the DragCanvas_.cs-file it works as I already said in my first post. Normally your suggestion should work. But it does not unfortunately:

Comment: @s950mpc2000: Where and how do you call `WriteLeftMarginInConsole()` in the `MainWindow`? You'll need to call it *after* you have set the properties of the `Canvas`.

Comment: I wrote the `public void WriteLeftMarginInConsole()`
        `{`
            `Console.WriteLine(dragCanvas_.TopMargin);`

        `}`
as a last method of MainWindow.xaml.cs, i.e. at the end of the MainWindow.xaml.cs-file.

Comment: @s950mpc2000: But how and where do you *call* it? It doesn't call itself...

Comment: I call it in the MainWindow.xaml.cs-file after the point, where the MainWindow opens in runtime. I don't know, I think I am missing a lot of basic concepts of C#. As I already said: I am very new to C# WPF and only programmed a very small project in C# with the Winforms Framework before. I will have a lot to read about C# this weekend. At which point of the code does it have to be called in order for it to work?

Comment: If you call the method before the properties have been set in your `OnPreviewMouseUp` event handler, what values are you expecting to get printed out?

Comment: I open a new question in which I describe the problem in more detail. This thread leads to nothing anymore, because it is only continues in form of comments instead of giving constructive answers or suggestions. My problem is that I never
worked with a `protected override void` method. 
However, I do understand the basic concept on how to get the values from variables which are in another class in a 
`protected override void` method.

Comment: In the DragCanvas_ class I write at the beginning `public double LeftMargin {get; set;}` and `public double TopMargin {get; set;}`, so that the variables are extracted out of the method of the DragCanvas_.cs class. However, in order to use these values I also have to create a new instance of the DragCanvas_ class. This However was already done in my xaml-file with `<jas:DragCanvas_ x:Name="dragCanvas_"`. The `dragCanvas_` object allows me to address the `LeftMargin` 
and `TopMargin`variable.

Comment: BUT, I do not know how to let the method `OnPreviewMouseUp` invoke before the `Console.WriteLine(LeftMargin)`; in 
the MainWindow.xaml.cs-class is invoked. This WPF-Framework is really confusing me. In a C# console app I would have 
`static public void Main(String[] args) {}`.

Comment: The order of properties being set has nothing to do with WPF. How should the main window be able to display values that do not yet exist?

Comment: `OnPreviewMouseUp` is invoked when you click, isn't it? And you cannot click before the main window has been shown?

Comment: Yeah, that is true. Therefore, I write the `WriteLeftMarginInConsole()`-method after the MainWindow has been shown. Maybe, you should write a real answer or suggestion, so that I can completely understand you. Your comments begin to confuse me.

Comment: After the main window is shown? You need to call if after you have clicked.

Comment: It is called after I have pressed left Mouse button down, have hold it and dragged the rectangle along and after releasing the mouseButton the coordinates LeftMargin and TopMargin of the rectangle are determined. That already works in the DragCanvas Class. I get the right coordinates of the new location of the rectangle after positioning it by dragging with the mouse to a new location.

Comment: What method is called after you have clicked the button? The one in the `MainWindow` class?

Comment: I edit my main-post in a few minutes,  so that you can understand what I mean. We talk at cross purposes.

Comment: I now wrote in the xaml-line of the rectangle `MouseLeftButtonUp="MouseUpROIRectangle1"` and my `MouseUpROIRectangle1` method of the MainWindow.xaml.cs-class is invoked if my mouse cursor is on the first rectangle and is released. Inside the `MouseUpROIRectangle1` method I invoke `Console.WriteLine(dragCanvas_.LeftMargin)`.Now I also get the coordinates inside a method in the Maindow.xaml.cs class.

Comment: I now marked your answer as a solution because it is the solution of my original question, i.e. how to access variables of another class, especially the DragCanvas_ class. You gave me the hint, that I do not have to create an instance of the DragCanvas_ class because that instance, i.e. the object of that class already existed and is accessable inside the MainWindow class. It was already created inside the xaml-file with the `</jas:...>`. I firstly did not know what the `</jas:...>` means and I just implemented it as it was written inside the documentation of the DragCanvas class.

Comment: @s950mpc2000: Great. Feel free to ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: Thanks :) I will do so, but as a seperate question on stackoverflow of course.